# PHP count all nodes in a tree

Tags: php, class, tree, nodes

I need to create a Node class that actually will be a tree of nodes and in the same class I need to create a function that will count all nodes in the tree including root element. 
I was able to do something with two classes (Node class and Tree class). I need to make it all in one class (Node) class.

something like:

```
class myclass
{
       //Array of nodes with childs 

        public function count();
}
```

Comment: Did you try something? We'd like to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
public function count() {
  $childCount = 0;
  foreach($this->childs as $c) $childCount+=$c->count();
  return 1 + $childCount;
}
```

Comment: how would be the structure of the Node Class in this example? I mean the whole class!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mode` parameter of the count() function.

```
public function count() {
    return count(array, COUNT_RECURSIVE);
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php for more information on the count function.